# He said that he have vs he had

Tags: tense, reported-speech

lets assume I saw my friend last night and he said exactly on of these to me:

> I've lost my keys.

or

> I Had lost my keys.

so, I know in reported speech I must convert "Have" to "Had".

> my friend said that she had lost her keys.

but second sentence has "had" itself, should I use the same reported speech for both sentences? If yes how do we Differentiate them? Thanks in advance

Comment: It's unlikely that anyone would say _I had lost my keys_ without any other information, because the past perfect implies that the keys are no longer missing. He might say _I thought I had lost my keys, but I found them in my coat pocket._ In reported speech: _He said that he had thought he had lost his keys, but he had found them in his coat pocket_.

Comment: Thanks @KateBunting,  so if I say this sentence : "she said she had lost her keys" to my friend, He doesn't understand Whether she had the key or not( at the time I spoke to her), unless I give more information . am I right?

Comment: "She said she had lost her keys" would be understood to mean that they were missing at the time she spoke, unless further information was added.

Answer (score 1):

You can't differentiate them. *I lost*, *I have lost*, and *I had lost* all become *she had lost* when you backshift them.

(You seem to be confused about *his* and *her*: if your friend is a "she" then she lost **her** keys).

Comment: so based on the context it can has two meanings? and I corrected the mistake .thanks.

Comment: Well, you might say two meanings. I would prefer to say that _I lost_, _I have lost_, and _I had lost_ could all refer to the same event in the past, but the speaker is choosing to present the temporal relationshbips differently. In reported speech, those fine distinctions are neutralised.